# Django allauth, require email verification for regular accounts but not for social accounts

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-allauth

So I'm using django-allauth, even though I've found a previous post pointing to the [configuration settings](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html) for setting the email verification settings, it looks like it's not working for me.

After using their facebook account to login, the user redirected to the e-mail verification form, I would like them to be signed in and be redirected to their profile page.

I have the following settings;

## settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
'signup': 'app.users.forms.CustomSignupForm',
}
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook':
       {'METHOD': 'oauth2',
        'SCOPE': ['email','public_profile'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
        'EXCHANGE_TOKEN': True,
        'LOCALE_FUNC': lambda request: 'nl_NL',
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': True,
        'VERSION': 'v2.4'}
}
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
```

Even though I understand it is possible for facebook users to have an account without a validated e-mail adres I would still like the facebook users to be automatically logged in after signing in with their facebook account.

## requirements.txt

python == 3.7

django == 2.1.3

django-allauth == 0.38.0

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but if someone has the same problem the solution is quite simple. You just have to add `SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'` to your settings.py file.

Also if you have set `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'`, social account verification will automatically be set to 'mandatory' as well.

https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html (at the end of the page)