# Django all-auth - Social login - Facebook - Pass without requesting email

Tags: django, settings, django-allauth

So I must be missing something, I've looked for similiar questions and tried their solutions like overhere ([Django allauth, require email verification for regular accounts but not for social accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53280805/django-allauth-require-email-verification-for-regular-accounts-but-not-for-soci))

I would like to let users interact with my webapp without requesting their e-mailadres after logging in with their social account, in this case with their facebook account.

I have the following set up;

## settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'optional'
    
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'optional'
```

At the moment, whenever someone tries to login with their facebook account, they get redirected to the signup form requesting for their email address.

Even though I'm using email as a authentication method for regular signups, this should not be necessary for social signups am I right?

Edit:

So I tried implementing Google as a social login provider, since google has a flag for email_verified I thought this might solve the problem.

Even though you can nog login with your Google account, the social login redirects to

```
/accounts/social/signup/
```

Not really sure why but I would like to skip this step for social logins.

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Allright, found something over here [Paypal redirects to /accounts/social/signup](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/722)

When using a social login while the email address is already in use, the signup form kicks and you have to submit your email address.

After signup, a message will be displayed saying the email address is already in use.